# Using Excel VBA to create an XML file

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I'm trying to create an XML file from VBA found in Excel, I'm a little hazy on the details though, I've never touched XML or VBA before in my life. I need to write out an XML file with in the following format:

```
<TextField0 xfdf:original="Brand Name">HEADING1</TextField0>
```

There will be a bunch of lines like this such as TextField1, which is "Product" and so on. The code I have thus far revelent to this section is this:

```
   'create Heading element
   Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("TextField0")
   objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement

   'create Attribute to the Heading Element and set value
   Set objXMLattr = objDom.createAttribute("xfdf:original")
   objXMLattr.NodeValue = "Brand Name"
   objXMLelement.setAttributeNode objXMLattr
```

That creates this output:

```
<TextField0 xfdf:original="Brand Name"/>
```

This is of coursem missing HEADING1 and I can't for the life of me figure out how to put that bit in there. I can't seem to append anything to an attribute. Any help will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HEADING1 is the text that belongs to the `TextField0` element, not the attribute.

So you can set it using the `objXmlElement.text` property.

In response to comment:

> I'm struggling to find documentation for this stuff

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766564(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good start.

Comment: Wow. How simple! Thanks a lot, I'm struggling to find documentation for this stuff.

Comment: Many thanks for the link to the "Program with DOM in Visual Basic" tutorial on MSDN - very helpful indeed.